# Adjust width of UIImageView in nib

Tags: ios

I'm really having trouble understanding why this isn't working: I have a UIImageView in the nib and I need to override its frame in viewDidLoad, because the width will be changing based on user input. Here's how I've tried to change its frame:

```
CGRect blueBarStart = blueBar.frame;
blueBarStart.size.width = .1*blueBarStart.size.width;
[blueBar setFrame:blueBarStart];
```

However `blueBar` is shown on load with its full, unaltered width. Not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out since I am using 'Left' as the mode for `UIImageView`, it is forcing the full image in it to be shown, regardless of what I set the width to be.

Answer (score 0):

The view is not fully loaded/configured during `viewDidLoad`, so any changes you make during `viewDidLoad` are probably being over written/reset.  Try moving your resizing code to `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work. The UIImageView is in a UIView separate from the nib, and it is added as a subview of a programmatically created UIScrollView in viewDidLoad...would that affect anything?

Comment: @bobnoble what do you mean by this? What isn't fully loaded or configured?

Comment: @CarlVeazey - when `viewDidLoad` in invoked, the view has not been laid out (i.e., the frame/bounds/etc of views are not necessarily known yet).  You can access the views and set some properties (e.g., the text on a `UILabel`, but can't rely on any layout values you access or set remaining the same.  At `viewWillAppear` the layout is complete and it is save to access and/or set layout properties.